# Как перестроить flex-элементы горкой?

Tags: css, flexbox

Помогите пожалуйста переверстать элементы

Есть несколько элементов. нужно чтобы на iPad вертикальной ориентации они располагались так:

```
00

00

00
```

,а на iPad горизонтальной ориентации, они располагались так:

```
_00_

0000
```

Я решил эту задачу, используя flex-элементы и скрытые элементы:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc8zduzs/1/)

[page](http://fh79272k.bget.ru/files/html/flex1/)

Но мне нужно решение, которой использует только возможности flexbox(без костылей в виде скрытых элементов)

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="icons_item icons_item_hide"><a class="icon" href=""></a></div>                  
    <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="images/circle_border.png"></a></div>          
    <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="images/circle_border.png"></a></div>   
    <div class="icons_item icons_item_hide"><a class="icon" href=""></a></div>        
    <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="images/circle_border.png"></a></div>          
    <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="images/circle_border.png"></a></div>          
    <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="images/circle_border.png"></a></div>          
    <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="images/circle_border.png"></a></div>          
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #999;
}

.wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

    .icons{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;        
        justify-content: space-around;  
        height: 100%;

    }

        .icons_item{
            width: 50%;
            height: 33%;
            display: flex;
        }

        .icons_item_hide{
            display: none;
        }

            .icon{
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }

                .icon img{
                    display: block;
                    width: 66%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }


/* iPad h*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {background: green;}
    .icons_item{
        width: 25%;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .icons_item_hide{
        display: block;
    }

        .icon img{
            width: 66%;
        }   

}

/* iPad v*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {background: maroon;}
    .icons_item{
        width: 50%;
        height: 33%;
    }

    .icons_item_hide{
        display: none;
    }   
        .icon img{
            width: 66%;
        }       
}

/* iphone6Plus */
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    body {background: orange;}
}

/* iphone6 */
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    body {background: lime;}
}

/* iphone5 */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    body {background: red;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой костыльный вариант)):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}



@media screen and (orientation: portrait) { 
  .icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

  }

  .icons_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) { 
  .icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;

  }
  
  .icons:before,
  .icons:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    order: -1;
  }

  .icons_item {
    width: 25%;
    
  }
  
  .icons_item:nth-of-type(1),
  .icons_item:nth-of-type(2) {
    order:-1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="icons">                
        <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Enneagram_circle.png"></a></div>          
        <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Enneagram_circle.png"></a></div>   
        <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Enneagram_circle.png"></a></div>          
        <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Enneagram_circle.png"></a></div>          
        <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Enneagram_circle.png"></a></div>          
        <div class="icons_item"><a class="icon" href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Enneagram_circle.png"></a></div>          
      </div>
    </div>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/luyage/edit?css,output) по изменяйте ширину, чтобы увидеть результат

**P.S:** *Да, поняла, чтобы без костылей, но ...*

Comment: Ну почему же костыльный? Вполне подходящий